# Can you explain how to project this vector onto the complex plane to someone who hasn't learned Differential Geometry or Topology?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

## Background

I am trying to understand the paper ["On $C^2$-smooth Surfaces of Constant Width" by Brendan Guilfoyle and Wilhelm Klingenberg](https://sword.cit.ie/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1023&context=dpttem_kpub). However, despite my efforts to decipher the paper, I can't follow everything it is describing. This paper is written around complex differential geometry and topology, and appears either to play fast and loose with notation or to rely on conventions I haven't encountered before. I have no prior experience with differential geometry or topology in general, and the (seemingly) flexible use of notation makes it difficult to follow without intimate familiarity with the conventions of the fields in question. I have been unable to find other resources on the same topic that are easier to parse, or lessons on how to understand the concepts in the paper that aren't either behind a paywall or *also* way over my head.

## What I Understand So Far

In **Section 2.1: The Space of Oriented Lines**, the authors say

> Let $$ be the set of oriented lines, or rays, in $^3$. Such a line $γ$ is uniquely determined by its unit direction vector $\vec{U}$ and the vector $\vec{V}$ joining the origin to the point on the line that lies closest to the origin. That is,
> $$
> γ = \{ \vec{V} + r \; \vec{U} ∈ ^3 \; | \; r ∈ ℝ \}
> $$
> where r is an affine parameter along the line.
>
> By parallel translation, we move $\vec{U}$ to the origin and $\vec{V}$ to the head of $\vec{U}$. Thus, we obtain a vector that is tangent to the unit 2-dimensional sphere in $^3$. The mapping is one-to-one and so it identifies the space of oriented lines with the tangent bundle of the 2-sphere $TS^2$ (see Figure 1).
> $$
>  = \{ (\vec{U}, \vec{V}) ∈ ^3 × ^3 \; | \quad |\vec{U}| = 1 \quad \vec{U} ⋅ \vec{V} = 0\}
> $$
> [image: Figure 1]
> $$
> \text{Fɪɢᴜʀᴇ 1.}
> $$

So far, so good. This all makes sense.

In **Section 2.2: Coordinates on** , the authors introduce $ξ$ as "the local complex coordinate on the unit 2-sphere in $^3$ obtained by stereographic projection from the south pole" in terms of standard spherical polar angles $(θ, φ)$ with the definition $ξ = \tan\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right) e^{i φ}$. That all checks out.

The next thing they say is

> We convert from coordinates $(ξ, \bar{ξ})$ back to $(θ, φ)$ using
> $$
> \cos(θ) = \frac{1 - ξ \bar{ξ}}{1 + ξ \bar{ξ}},\quad \sin(θ) = \frac{2 \sqrt{ξ \bar{ξ}}}{1 + ξ \bar{ξ}},\quad \cos(φ) = \frac{ξ + \bar{ξ}}{2 \sqrt{ξ \bar{ξ}}},\quad \sin(φ) = \frac{ξ - \bar{ξ}}{2 i \sqrt{ξ \bar{ξ}}}
> $$

I know the conversion from unit-spherical coordinates $(θ, φ)$ to Cartesian coordinates is $(\sin(θ) \cos(φ), \sin(θ) \sin(φ), \cos(θ))$, and these equations all check out.

## Where I Get Confused

Continuing farther into Section 2.2 is where I run into trouble, as the authors add another complex variable $η$ without defining it in a way I understand:

> This can be extended to complex coordinates $(ξ, η)$ on  minus the tangent space over the south pole, as follows. First note that a tangent vector $\vec{X}$ to the 2-sphere can always be expressed as a linear combination of the tangent vectors generated by $θ$ and $φ$:
> $$
> \vec{X} = X^θ \frac{∂}{∂ θ} + X^φ \frac{∂}{∂ φ}.
> $$
> In our complex formalism, we have the natural complex tangent vector
> $$
> \frac{∂}{∂ ξ} = \cos\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)^2 \left(\frac{∂}{∂ θ} - \frac{i}{2 \cos\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)} \frac{∂}{∂ φ}\right) e^{-i φ},
> $$
> and any real tangent vector can be written as
> $$
> \vec{X} = η \frac{∂}{∂ ξ} + \bar{η} \frac{∂}{∂ \bar{ξ}}.
> $$
> for a complex number $η$. We identify the real tangent vector $\vec{X}$ on the 2-sphere (and hence the ray in $^3$) with the two complex numbers $(ξ, η)$. Loosely speaking, $ξ$ determines the direction of the ray, and $η$ determines its perpendicular distance vector to the origin — complex representations of the vectors $\vec{U}$ and $\vec{V}$.

I get that $\vec{U}$ is being projected from $^3$ into the complex plane as $ξ$, since $\vec{U}$ is a unit vector with its base on the origin and its head on the unit sphere at position $(θ, φ)$. However, I don't understand how $\vec{V}$ gets converted to $η$. $\vec{V}$ is not necessarily of unit length, so it can't be as simple as $\vec{U}$'s projection. There seem to be a number of different ways to project $\vec{V}$ into the complex plane, and I'm not sure which is correct.

***Can you explain the conversion between $\vec{V}$ and $η$ to someone whose formal math education hasn't gone past Calc 1?***

Specifically, based on the next sections of the paper, I need to be able to convert from coordinates $(ξ, η)$ to the vectors $\vec{U}$ and $\vec{V}$. I completely understand the definition for $\vec{U}(ξ)$, so I just need to know how to derive a definition for $\vec{V}(η)$ or $\vec{V}(ξ, η)$.

Comment: It seems to me you're going to need at least Calc 2 and Calc 3 to understand things. Not to mention some differential geometry. It is common to work with $\xi$ and $\bar\xi$ as two complex coordinates on the complexified plane. They look like they are not independent (after all, if you know a complex number, you know its complex conjugate), but look: If $\xi=x+iy$, then $x=\frac12(\xi+\bar\xi)$ and $y=\frac1{2i}(\xi-\bar\xi)$. So, working with complex coefficients, these do give independent coordinates.

Comment: The product X×Y of any two spaces denotes the space of all ordered pairs, X×Y = {(x,y)  | x ∈ X and y ∈ Y} endowed with the product topology. If these are metric spaces, then X×Y is often endowed with the cartesian product metric of the metrics d_X on X and d_Y on Y.

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you know what specific parts of Calc 2 and Calc 3 are important for understanding this, so I can look for resources that explain them?

Comment: I wrote some stuff up, but I have to admit, this is one of my worse/ad-hoc answers, because it’s pretty much impossible to explain things in a natural way when you don’t have the necessary prerequisites. Also, I don’t understand why you’re trying to read Klingenberg’s paper without the necessary background. Just for comparison: if I went back in time to anything before my 3rd year (i.e prior to full on courses on linear algebra, calculus on manifolds and an intro to differential geometry), I would not be able to read this paper. You really are trying to run without having crawled.

Comment: @peek-a-boo My end-goal is to generate a 3D model of the surface in the paper's Figure 5, subject to some specific requirements about point distribution and symmetry. Being able to "run" (fluent in all prerequisites) would certainly make it easier to reach that goal, but I'm hoping that I can crawl my way there in less total time & effort than learning to run first and *then* running to it.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Long-term, I do hope to study more advanced mathematics, but right now I'm hoping for a set of steps I can follow to get the right answer for this project and just enough understanding to troubleshoot a wrong answer and/or adapt the steps to any related project(s) in the near-future.

Answer (score 1):

How would I explain it to someone who has not learnt anything beyond calc 1? Very vaguely:

The vector $\vec{V}$ lives inside of three-dimensional space (clear from the picture). But also clear from the picture is that $\vec{V}$ is in fact orthogonal to $\vec{U}$, meaning that $\vec{V}$ lies inside a specific 2-dimensional space, the *tangent space to the sphere (at the point $U$)*. The fact that $\vec{V}$ lives in this two dimensional space means that we really only need two numbers to “fully describe it”, rather than the expected three. Now, given the coordinate system $(\theta,\varphi)$ on the sphere, one can introduce two vector (fields) $\mathbf{v}_{\theta}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{\varphi}$, which are roughly speaking, vectors that are respectively pointing along which the coordinates $\theta,\varphi$ are increasing while the other stays fixed (this is a very bad explanation, but a better one would require several more pages of writing given your lack of background knowledge, and I’m not going to do that). These two vectors $\{\mathbf{v}_{\theta},\mathbf{v}_{\varphi}\}$ form a basis for the tangent planes to the sphere, so given any vector $\vec{X}$ tangent to the sphere, we can express it as a linear combination of these guys:
\begin{align}
\vec{X}=X^{\theta}\cdot\mathbf{v}_{\theta}+X^{\varphi}\cdot\mathbf{v}_{\varphi},\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
for some numbers which I call $X^{\theta},X^{\varphi}$ depending on the vector $\vec{X}$ (note that $X^{\theta}$ is the name of the number… it is not $X$ raised to some power $\theta$). At this stage, we can note that no one forces us to use $\{\mathbf{v}_{\theta},\mathbf{v}_{\varphi}\}$ as a basis. Just as we introduced ‘real vectors’ associated to the real coordinate system $(\theta,\varphi)$, one can introduce ‘complex vectors’ (these live in the *complexification* of the real tangent space) $\{\mathbf{u}_{\xi},\mathbf{u}_{\overline{\xi}}\}$ (I’m calling them $\mathbf{u}$ instead of $\mathbf{v}$ just to highlight that they’re a different type of beast from what we see above).

How **exactly** does one define these things? Well, first write $\xi=\alpha+i\beta$. Then, $(\alpha,\beta)$ provides us a real coordinate system, so we already understand how this gives us two tangent vectors $\{\mathbf{v}_{\alpha},\mathbf{v}_{\beta}\}$. Now, define the vectors
\begin{align}
\mathbf{u}_{\xi}&:=\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{v}_{\alpha}-i\mathbf{v}_{\beta}\right),\quad\text{and}\quad \mathbf{u}_{\overline{\xi}}= \frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{v}_{\alpha}+i\mathbf{v}_{\beta}\right).
\end{align}
This is just a definition. Why is the definition like this? I can’t spend the time to tell you that now.

One can of course rearrange them into $\mathbf{v}_{\alpha}=\mathbf{u}_{\xi}+\mathbf{u}_{\overline{\xi}}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{\beta}=i(\mathbf{u}_{\xi}-\mathbf{u}_{\overline{\xi}})$.
By applying the logic $(*)$ to the coordinate system $(\alpha,\beta)$, we see that
\begin{align}
\vec{X}&=X^{\alpha}\mathbf{v}_{\alpha}+ X^{\beta}\mathbf{v}_{\beta}\\
&=(X^{\alpha}+iX^{\beta})\mathbf{u}_{\xi}+(X^{\alpha}-iX^{\beta})\mathbf{u}_{\overline{\xi}}.
\end{align}
This particular combination $X^{\alpha}+iX^{\beta}$ is what the paper is calling $\eta$ (or really $\eta(\vec{X})$ since it depends on $\vec{X}$). Notice also that $\eta$ and its complex conjugate $\overline{\eta}$ appear.

---

So as a summary:

- the vector $\vec{V}$ lives in a certain 2-dimensional subspace, so it really only needs two real numbers to be fully described.
- given the complex coordinate system $\xi=\alpha+i\beta$ on the sphere, one can define two *coordinate-induced vector fields* $\{\mathbf{v}_{\alpha},\mathbf{v}_{\beta}\}$ (you can ask how these guys are related to $\{\mathbf{v}_{\theta},\mathbf{v}_{\varphi}\}$, and the answer is essentially by the *chain rule*). These are typically denoted $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}$. Why? I can’t tell you now.
- from this one can define the corresponding complex versions $\{\mathbf{u}_{\xi},\mathbf{u}_{\overline{\xi}}\}$ (which are typically denoted $\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi}, \frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{\xi}} $).
- so if we have a real tangent vector $\vec{X}$, then we can always decompose it (multivariable calculus/linear algebra/basic differential geometry) into $\vec{X}=X^{\alpha}\mathbf{v}_{\alpha}+X^{\beta}\mathbf{v}_{\beta}$ for some $X^{\alpha},X^{\beta}\in\Bbb{R}$.
- by defining $\eta(\vec{X})=X^{\alpha}+iX^{\beta}\in\Bbb{C}$, we immediately see that $\vec{X}=\eta(X)\cdot \mathbf{u}_{\xi}+\overline{\eta(X)}\cdot \mathbf{u}_{\overline{\xi}}$. Hence, knowledge of the single complex number $\eta(\vec{X})$ fully and uniquely determines the tangent vector $\vec{X}$. That is how a vector tangent to the sphere is being associated to a complex number.

Comment: I understand that $\vec{V}$ is confined to a plane and thus only has two degrees of freedom once $\vec{U}$ is known. What I don't understand is how to find an equation for converting coordinates $(ξ, η)$ to $\vec{V}$; can you elaborate on that? The theory behind it is nice to know, but I'm more interested in the application under these narrow circumstances.

Comment: @Lawton there are many different bases relative to which one can express $\vec{V}$ (the ambient cartesian basis so you get a triplet of numbers depending on two parameters, the spherical basis, the $\{\mathbf{v}_{\alpha},\mathbf{v}_{\beta}\}$, or $\{\mathbf{u}_{\xi},\mathbf{u}_{\overline{\xi}}\}$ bases). Which one are you looking for?

Comment: The one that applies with equation (2.1) in Proposition 2.2 on page 4 of the paper.

Comment: @Lawton that’s the easiest one. Given a complex number $\eta$, you use the second equation on page $4$ to construct the vector, and just plug in the definition in the first equation if you want to make things fully explicit.

Comment: I (mostly) figured out the part I was stuck on. I was drastically overthinking what I needed to do because of how complicated the notation seemed.